# Why won't binding to a $scope string value from a ui-bootstrap modal controller work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I'm using ui-bootstrap to handle my modals. I'm passing $scope in as the scope parameter, it looks something like this:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/pages/gethelp/modals/bulk_change.html',
    controller: BulkChangeCtrl,
    size: 'lg',
    scope: $scope,
    backdrop:"static",
    resolve: {
      type: function() { return type; },
      field:function() { return field; },
      preset: function() { return preset; }
    }
  });
```

Inside my modal controller, I'm defining a single model string value that I want to both bind to inputs as well as use as the selected value when the user hits submit. This is simple and is setup like:

```
$scope.val = "";
```

Yet, in my submit function that's called via a button click, no matter what, $scope.val is empty. It's like the functions are referencing a completely different version of $scope.val. Yet in my view, I can bind to {{val}} no problem.

Why is this? When I update my code to be something like:

```
$scope.obj = { val:"" };
```

It all works as expected and I can bind to {{obj.val}}. What am I completely missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because bootstrap creates a child scope (@`var modalScope = (modalOptions.scope || $rootScope).$new();`) of provided scope with scope argument. So in angular child scopes prototypical inherit from the parent. And primitive types (when there is no `.` in the binding) will not be consulted for in the prototype chain and will add a new property `val` and update it which will not be reflected in the underlying scope, only updates to reference types will (object, function reference etc..) have the changes reflected and hence `obj.val` works since the parent scope also has reference to the same `obj`.

So when you do:-

```
 $scope.val = "";
```

new child scope created out of the provided scope will update `val` at the child since it is not updated as a value on a reference type, you wont see it updated at its parent .

Here is a [good read](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: The general idea is correct, but I don't think this sentence `And primitive types will not get carry forwarded to the child scope, only reference types will` is true. Nothing will get carry forwarded. Instead they will be act as a fallback if the requested property doesn't exist in child scope.

Comment: No, regardless of the property exists on the prototype chain or not, it will always add a new property.

Comment: The same hold true for reference types, if we are talking about the first level (direct) property `$scope.val` or `$scope.obj`. The different start from using the second level property `$scope.obj.val`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59219/discussion-between-runtarm-and-psl).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply and link. This makes a little more sense - I'll check out the article and hopefully have a better understanding of how $scope inheritance works.

Comment: @runTarm Sorry man i cant access it here (its blocked)... Probably i updated my answer to reflect in a better language (I suck at  it :)).. hopefully that makes sense...

Comment: Ah dealt with this problem the other day found my answer here : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes